# React Hooks must be called in a React function component when using React RTK query createApi

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I'm creating 2 endponits using React RTK query

```
export const countryApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: "countryApi",
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: "https://restcountries.com/v3.1/" }),
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getCountries: builder.query({
    query: () => `all/`
    }),
   getCountryByName: builder.query({
    query: (name) => `name/${name}`
    })
  })
});
```

Then i need to show results with condition, if the state of search input change i call the second endponit otherwise i use the 1st enpoint to show all the list of countries

```
// country search state
const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
let countryData;
countryData =
  search === ""
    ? useGetCountriesQuery().data
    : useGetCountryByNameQuery(search,{skip: search ===""}).data;
```

But i got an error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEZAS.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call hooks conditionally, that is against [the rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level).

hooks must be called every time, in the same order, when a render functions runs. By having that ternary, this is not guaranteed to happen:

```
countryData =
  search === ""
    ? useGetCountriesQuery().data
    : useGetCountryByNameQuery(search,{skip: search ===""}).data;
```

You might call `useGetCountriesQuery` in one render cycle, and `useGetCountryByNameQuery` in another.

One way to solve this would be to call both hooks unconditionally, but `skip` them vice-versa. Or, combine the two queries into one hook if possible:

```
const countries = useGetCountriesQuery({ skip: search !== '' })
const countriesByName = useGetCountryByNameQuery(search,{skip: search ===""})

const countryData = search === "" ? countries.data : countriesByName.data
```